# Write into file and compare different values versus comparing different values with sleep in bash?

Tags: bash

What's the best way to deal with jobs that need to compare changing values, for example:

I want to calculate lines per minute

I can count lines in a log file with grep and wc, sleep 60 second, read lines again and substract the two values to get lines per minute:

```
lines="$(cat some.log | wc -l)"
sleep 60
newlines="$(cat some.log | wc -l)"
result="$(echo "$newlines - lines" | bc)"
printf "$result\n"
```

Or I can write the results in a file and run the script every minute with a cronjob:

```
read lines < /tmp/lines.txt
newlines="$(cat some.log | wc -l)"

#Calculate result
result="$(echo "$newlines - $lines" | bc)"

#write lines
echo "$lines" > /tmp/lines.txt

#write result
echo "$result" > /tmp/result.txt
```

The only thing I can think of is the file option is more appropriate for other scripts, so they can read result.txt instantaneously and don't have to wait 60 seconds for execution.

Comment: I'm not sure "best" can really be answered here. It really comes down to what works for you. For example, you could accomplish the easily accessible value of your second method without leaving a file behind with a creative use of netcat with a sixty second timeout and loops.

Comment: I would go with the crontab, but that's just my opinion. There might be no correct answer the way you are asking it and you might get a lot of suggestions and opinion based answers, which is not what this site is about. Maybe you can try reframing your question so it is according to [this](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/): You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Answer (score 0):

The methods you mentioned using are fine. I would like to suggest one more in case you can try.use the time command to extract script execution time.

```
time <yourscript> >log_file
```

.

extract minutes and seconds from to get the number of lines / minute.

```
(line_count) / (no of minutes from log_file)
```